# Legal to make an app that organizes other people's youtube videos?

Tags: copyright, software, ownership

I'd like to make a mobile application that organizes youtube videos into groups, allowing the user to browse groups and watch videos.

For example - I'd like to organize certain cooking videos (not made by me - linking to content made by someone else) in a helpful way.

I cannot find literature helping me understand if this is allowed or not. Can someone help me find the right rules to read?

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Linking to content is one thing, copying someone elses content is another.

Comment: If no copy would take place (e.g., only store video URLs), including the arrangement of the content (you do not copy the arrangement of the video collections from other sources), I do not see copyright infringement.

Comment: @brandin - I'm linking to content. Not copying the content. I can't find the rules clarifying if just arranging someone else's content (links to youtube videos) is allowable in legal rules or app store rules.

Answer (score 3):

I know of an app that did similar. They sold membership access and linked Youtube videos. One of the Youtuber's started to take legal action against them. I don't know what happened but the app blocked their content from being shown.

Updated this comment to remove incorrect information. After looking at Youtube's recent terms and conditions; you aren't allowed to link, embed or use the API if you want to put content behind a paywall, or show it alongside advertising:

Under the section: **Permissions and Restrictions**

https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=GB&template=terms

So long as your app is free, and doesn't contain advertising you are probably okay.